# How to show $\tanh^{-1}(3i)=i\tan^{-1}(3)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I want to find all the complex values associated with $\tanh^{-1}(3i)$. On WolframAlpha, it computes $\tanh^{-1}(3i)=i\tan^{-1}(3)$. I know that $\tanh^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \log{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ and so

$$\begin{align}
\tanh^{-1}(3i)&=\frac{1}{2} \log{\frac{1+3i}{1-3i}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{-8+6i}{10}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{-4+3i}{5}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{-4+3i}{5}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln(5)+\arg(-4+3i)-[\ln(5)+\arg(5)]\Big]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\arg(-4+3i)+2\pi n\Big]\\
\end{align}$$

Where do I go from here to simplify it to $i\tan^{-1}(3)$?

Comment: Notice that $\tanh$ is $i\pi$-periodic. Also, you obviously mean $i\arctan3$, not $i\tan3$, otherwise it's wrong. You may use the fact that $\sin iz=i\sinh z$ and $\cos iz=\cosh z$, hence $\tan iz=i\tanh z$.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to relate $\tanh^{-1}$ with  $\tan?$ You have the general identity $\tanh^{-1}(iz)= i \tan^{-1}(z)$

Answer (score 2):

put $\arg(-4+3i)=2\theta$

$\displaystyle\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=-\frac{3}{4} $

$\displaystyle\tan\theta=3$

$\displaystyle\theta=i\tan^{-1}3$

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

by definition of the hyperbolic functions we have:
$$
\tanh (ix)=\frac{\sinh (ix)}{\cosh (ix)}=\frac {i\sin x}{\cos x}=i \tan x
$$

that, for $\tan x=3 \iff x=\tan^{-1}(3)$, becomes:
$$
\tanh \left(i\tan^{-1}(3) \right)=3i
$$
and, using the definition of the inverse function, this is:
$$
 i\tan^{-1}(3)=\tanh^{-1}(3i)
$$

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive argument is to use the known Maclaurin series expansions:
$$\tanh^{-1}(z) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
$$\tan^{-1}(z) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
Now compute
$$\tanh^{-1}(iz) 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^{2k+1}z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i(-1)^kz^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
= i \tan^{-1}(z)
$$